# jQueryMobile Checkbox fires change event for entire controlgroup

Tags: jquery

I have a set of checkboxes setup in a series of div fieldcontain + fieldset controlgroups. They are grouped by topic with 12 main topics and 2-5 sub-topic under each.

When I "change" a checkbox, it fires the change event for the entire controlgroup. If I remove the control group fieldset, it fires the change event (when tapped) for the entire list, whether I use input[name="checkbox_name"] or input.checkbox-class.

How do I get the change for *just* the actual checkbox changed (from unchecked to checked or checked to unchecked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Matt Ball but I found this did what I needed:

`$('input[name="subtopics_chosen"]:checked').live('change',function()`

Before I had

`$('input[name="subtopics_chosen"]').live('change',function()`

I'll keep your StopPropagation tip for another day, though, I did not know about it.

Comment: Ah, you solved your own problem - don't forget to accept your own answer when the site will allow it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're doing something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function ()
{
    // stuff
});
```

You can prevent the event from bubbling using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function (e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can stop event bubbing *and* prevent other event handlers on the same element from running using [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).